# como saber en que base de datos se encuentra un procedimiento sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar , tengo 100 base de datos y quisiera buscar un procedimiento almacenado , que con un query me muestre la ubicacion de la base de datos que tiene ese procedimiento:

He realizado este Script pero siempre y cuando estoy en una base de datos especifica me muestra . Pero cuando estoy en la bd master y ejecuto no me muestra, lo que yo quisiera que cuando estoy en la bd master ejecute un script y me indique en que base de datos se encuentra

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'nombre de procedimiento'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'if exists(select 1 from [?].sys.objects where name=''nombre de procedimiento'')
select ''?'' as FoundInDatabase from [?].sys.objects where name=''nombre de procedimiento'''

Comment: Excelente Maestro